# How to programmatically align two Textviews and a Seekbar in the same line?

Tags: java, android

How to programmatically align a textview, a seekbar and another textview in the same line in android studio?

> Textview seekbar textview

I have written the following code snippet:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams sblayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        sblayoutParams.setMargins(10, 100, 10, 10);

        tv1.setText("0");
        tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
        tv1.setLayoutParams(sblayoutParams);
        sb1.setLayoutParams(sblayoutParams);
        tv2.setText("100");
        tv2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
        tv2.setLayoutParams(sblayoutParams);


        LinearLayout sblinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootContainer);

        // Add SeekBar to LinearLayout
        if (sblinearLayout != null) {
            sblinearLayout.addView(sb1);
            sblinearLayout.addView(tv1);
            sblinearLayout.addView(tv2);
        }
```

The following is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootContainer"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Current scenario:

[image]

Comment: Don't know what did you mean by ***align*** in the same line but `tv1`, `tv2` and `sb1` must have their own layout params.

Comment: @Darkman If I add their separate params then what should I do to align them such that tv1 , seekbar and  tv2 comes at the same horizontal level?

Comment: You know it is easier to replay/answer to anything related to GUI with at least a picture.

Comment: Try resizing the `View`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the `LinearLayout` has `android:orientation="vertical"`, so the `View`s appear one below the other.

If you want them to appear side by side, you should change the orientation to `android:orientation="horizontal"`

Or you can set the orientation programmatically:

```
sbLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL)
```

Change the width to `WRAP_CONTENT` and set a weight so all three `View`s get a third of the available width:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams sblayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

sblayoutParams.setMargins(10, 100, 10, 10);
sbLayoutParams.setWeight(1.0f);

tv1.setText("0");
tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
tv1.setLayoutParams(sblayoutParams);
sb1.setLayoutParams(sblayoutParams);
tv2.setText("100");
tv2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
tv2.setLayoutParams(sblayoutParams);


LinearLayout sblinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootContainer);

// Add SeekBar to LinearLayout
if (sblinearLayout != null) {
    sblinearLayout.addView(tv1);
    sblinearLayout.addView(sb1);
    sblinearLayout.addView(tv2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To adjust the margins of a view programmatically is not an easy job. You need to use the right LayoutParams for that view. To make things worst, there are bunch of them. One way that I know is using `instanceof` like the following:

```java
if(tv1.getLayoutParams() instanceof LinearLayout.LayoutParams) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You have to test with every single `LayoutParams`, so good luck with that. To make story short, in your context, you need to use `LinearLayout.Params`:

```java
LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tvparams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 100); //left, top, right, bottom
        
LinearLayout.LayoutParams sbparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
sbparams.setMargins(10, 100, 10, 0); //left, top, right, bottom
        
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("0");
tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
tv1.setLayoutParams(tvparams);

SeekBar sb1 = new SeekBar(this);
sb1.setMax(100); 
sb1.setProgress(100);
sb1.setLayoutParams(sbparams);

LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.rootContainer);
layout.addView(tv1);
layout.addView(sb1);
```

[EDIT]

If you just want to them in same spot, I recommend using xml like following:

**seekbar.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Text"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#999999"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

And change a bit in your main layout to look like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootContainer"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/seekbar" />

</LinearLayout>
```